# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "values" syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

```
'''


c.execute("""CREATE TABLE values(
        hv integer,
        vv integer,
        maxHeight integer,
        horrizontalDistance integer
        )""")
'''


def submit():


    conn = sqlite3.connect('values.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
   


       #insert to table
    c.execute("INSERT INTO values VALUES(v, h, a)",
            {
                

                'v': v.get(),
                'h': h.get(),
                'a': a.get()
                    
             })

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    
    v.delete(0, END)
    h.delete(0, END)
    a.delete(0, END)
```

This code is part of a larger program I'm developing, but when I run the whole thing it returns:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "values": syntax error
```

And highlights line 22, But I do not understand why, or what I have done wrong?

Comment: I dont think you can name a table 'values', its a reserved word.

Comment: If you want to use a reserved word as a table name, you need to quote it.

Comment: As well as the above observations, if you aren't inserting all the columns you need to specify those which you are inserting `INSERT INTO tbl (c1, c2, c3) VALUES (v1, v2, v3)`